# Where to place a bash command while building debian package

Tags: debian, apt, packaging

I need to build a debian package using `sbuild`. This package has dependencies that it can't automatically resolve - specifically the dependencies point to versions for which there are already newer versions available, but I need to stick to the old versions. As a result installation of these dependencies fails, so does the whole build. I was told, that I can't resolve it through `debian/control` in which I would indicate the desired versions (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379523/install-specific-package-version-through-meta-package).

I noticed that I can still install these dependencies manually with `apt-get install dep1=x.y.z`, so it is only the dependency resolution mechanism during package building which prevents me from installing the proper version of dependencies. How can I insert custom bash command that would install the dependencies in desired version with `apt-get` before `debian/control` is parsed and dependencies are resolved? I was thinking about overriding `debian/rules` but maybe there is a different place in `debian/*` files for such customizations?

Answer (score 3):

As you’ve determined, strict version dependencies in `debian/control` can’t help here.

To answer the general question in the title, shell commands in a Debian package build go in `debian/rules` or in files called from there. For example, in `debian/rules` (using `dh` style):

```
override_dh_auto_build:
        # your shell commands here ...
        dh_auto_build
        # ... or here
```

Various override styles are possible now (`execute_after_...` etc.).

However, this won’t help in this situation either, because package builds aren’t allowed to install (or remove) other packages during the build. `debian/control` (or rather, the result of processing `debian/control` in the source package) is supposed to fully specify the build dependencies; this is then satisfied by the build tools (`pbuilder`, `sbuild`, etc.), and *then* the build is started. By the time anything in your package gets a chance to run any commands, it’s too late.

As far as I’m aware, the only way to handle your scenario, with separate packages, is to create a *repository* containing the specific versions of packages you need, and then make that available in the build context. This would also provide the run-time dependencies needed to install the binary packages produced by your build.

Another approach would be to vendor your dependencies, *i.e.* include their *contents* in your source package (and adjust the build appropriately).

Comment: I have such repository already. The problem is that I also have another repository (nvidia repo) connected that provides me with newer versions of packages than I need. I can't disconnect from it, because I still need other stuff (cuda drivers, etc). How about I instruct `sbuild` with a command to copy a predefined file to `/etc/apt/preferences.d` which would prioritize my repository over nvidia? Where should I do this?

Comment: Since you’re using `sbuild`, can’t you configure the build chroot so that it only has your repository, and not the NVIDIA repository? Does your *build* actually need the CUDA drivers?

Comment: As I said, I need both repos in chroot. If other options are possible, I can't modify the chroot, because I do not own and maintain it - it's a chroot on which multiple jobs of various people are running in Jenkins, so this change might potentially affect them. I'd prefer to fix this problem through the contents of `debian/*` only.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn’t the sort of thing you can address using content in `debian/*`; as I said, once that’s involved, it’s too late, the dependencies have been set up. You could use an `sbuild` hook; see [the section on external commands in the `sbuild` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/sbuild/sbuild.1.en.html#EXTERNAL_COMMANDS).